# SQL - Two SUMS on the same column need to be mutually exclusive

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL query in MySQL Workbench that will return to me the sums of records I moved to a particular status considering only the latest timestamp for a particular record. I also need to do this *without* a sub query (or nested select).

Given the below table, I want to know that user with id **1** moved two records to status with id **2**. I need to not include in my counts if the same record was moved to two different status ids, but only count the latest status id.

### Table

| user_id | acted_on_record_id | moved_to_status_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 2 | 2022-01-01 19:39:37 |
| 1 | 1234 | 3 | 2022-01-02 19:39:37 |
| 1 | 1234 | 2 | 2022-01-03 19:39:37 |
| 1 | 5678 | 2 | 2022-01-03 19:39:37 |

Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.acted_on_record_id,
SUM(DISTINCT IF(t1.moved_to_status_id = 3, 1, 0)) AS pending,
SUM(DISTINCT IF(t1.moved_to_status_id = 2, 1, 0)) AS open,
MAX(t1.timestamp) as timestamp
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.user_id, t1.acted_on_record_id
```

This is the result I want:

| user_id | acted_on_record_id | pending | open | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 0 | 1 | 2022-01-03 19:39:37 |
| 1 | 5678 | 0 | 1 | 2022-01-03 19:39:37 |

However, my query gives me this result:

| user_id | acted_on_record_id | pending | open | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 1 | 1 | 2022-01-03 19:39:37 |
| 1 | 5678 | 0 | 1 | 2022-01-03 19:39:37 |

It shows a 1 in both pending and 1 in open columns because the SUM IF aggregates are not mutually exclusive or distinct on the acted_on_record_id. Is there a way to have these two aggregates know about each other and only sum the one with the greater timestamp without using a sub query (nested select)?

Comment: Why do you have `DISTINCT`? It makes no sense in `SUM()`.

Comment: Why can't you use subqueries? Can you use window functions (MySQL 8.x)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1 for how to get the latest record for each record ID.

Comment: @Barmar, if I take off the DISTINCT inside the SUM(), the record 1234 will get counted twice as open. Why does it not make sense? I cannot use window functions unfortunately, this query needs to run in Spring JPA eventually as a native query and we are using MySQL 5.7 there. I had initially gotten this working with a subquery, but the execution time went from 0.5 seconds to 15 seconds. Efficiency is the reason I would like to avoid a subquery. I will take a look at the link you provided, thanks!

Comment: `DISTINCT` doesn't make it use only the latest record. It makes it sum each value of the `IF()` once.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get the latest row in each group without a subquery or window function. To solve the performance problem, make sure you have a multi-column index on `acted_on_record_id, timestamp`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your input, using the link you provided I did eventually figure it out without the use of a subquery. I posted my final solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out by expanding on a solution here: [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1)

I used a LEFT JOIN to compare the table against itself. This query returned in 1.095 seconds where my prior solution (not posted) using a subquery returned in 15.268 seconds.

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.acted_on_record_id,
SUM(IF(t1.moved_to_status_id = 3, 1, 0)) AS pending,
SUM(IF(t1.moved_to_status_id = 2, 1, 0)) AS open
MAX(t1.timestamp) as timestamp
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table1 t2
  ON (t1.acted_on_record_id = t2.acted_on_record_id AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE t2.user_id IS NULL
group by t1.user_id, t1.acted_on_record_id, t1.moved_to_status_id
```